# Problem in configuring MySql 5.5 instance

Tags: mysql

I have problem in configuring the MySQL 5.5 instance. I have successfully installed the server and now trying to install the instance through configuration wizard. I am getting the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this message tells, that the client cannot connect to the mysql on local host...

this can have several reasons:

- the client is not running on the same machine as your mysql database ( therefore you have to replace localhost by the machines name, where the database is running )
- you didn't start the mysql server
- a firewall ( i.e. windows firewall ) blocked the TCP port 3306
- your mysql server runs on another port ( check the my.cnf, to see how it got configured )

Comment: How can I check the firewall settings in Windows XP.